# UITextField - resignFirstResponder Query

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextfield, resignfirstresponder

I have an application which has a couple of UITextField present to allow my user to enter their age, and another numerical value.  Ideally, I want the keyboard to bring up the numeric keypad when the TextField is being edited.  At present I have it set to Numer and Punctuation merely to make use of the 'Done' button to dismiss the keyboard as the Numeric pad does not have a done button.

In an attempt to use the Numeric keypad, I have tried to set it to dismiss by tapping the background of my main view.

```
-(IBAction)backgroundTapped:(id)sender;
```

I created the above action in my header file.

```
-(IBAction)backgroundTapped:(id)sender {
    [ageEntry resignFirstResponder];
}
```

I have expanded on the above method in my implementation file to tell the ageEntry TextField to resignFirstResponder.  I have also changed my main view to a UIControl class and connected the buttonTapped action to the relevant alert through Interface Builder.  Yet when I touch the background nothing happens.

Any ideas?

Comment: you want to add done button into numeric keyboard ?

Comment: Well ideally id like a done button in the numeric keypad, but that isnt in the options. I want to be able to tap my background to dismiss the keypad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just detect the touch in your viewController's view using the method

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [urAgeField resignFirstResponder];
    [urOtherField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

and resign the keyboard in this method

Comment: This looks like a much better solution +1.

Answer (score 1):

A much easier method is to add a `inputAccessoryView` to your text field. This input accessory view can be a `UIToolbar` with a single `UITabBarButton` for your *Done* button.

Much less of a hack, and will look like the accessory view that is used in for example Safari to dismiss the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

i had a similar problem. here is [the solution](http://www.neoos.ch/news/46-development/54-uikeyboardtypenumberpad-and-the-missing-return-key)..

**EDITED**

add

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
        [super viewDidLoad];
         UITapGestureRecognizer* tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                    action:@selector(tap:)];
        tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;

        [self addGestureRecognizer:tap];


}

- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
   [ageEntry resignFirstResponder];            
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But that isnt a solution to the issue per se, that is a very time consuming hack.

Comment: you need IBOutlet UITextFiled *ageEntry;